# Apply map over specific axis in a tensor

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, image-processing, matrix

I am looking for a function in `tensorflow` similar to `tf.map_fn` but takes also the specified axis I want to apply the map over, `tf.map_fn` applies the map over axis 0 by default but there is no parameter to change that, I would like it to map over axis 2, is there such a function? If not, is there any workaround that will still allow me to leverage TensorFlow's GPU & parallelization features? Something analogous to `np.apply_along_axis`.

Comment: So, what you're trying to do with "map( tensor3D, fn, axis=2)" is return an array with one entry per axis 2 index, consisting of "fn( tensor3D( :, :, i) for i in tensor3D.shape[2]" ?

Comment: Yes, I edited for more clarification that's something analogous to `np.apply_along_axis`.

Comment: I wonder if you could do it by swapping axes, doing the axis-0 map, then swapping axes back again?

Comment: I am working with videos frame by frame, any extra operations means extra time, I will consider this if it there is not anything else, but how to do that efficiently in tensorflow? the swapping axes?

Comment: I believe that "reshape" is essentially free, since all it does is switch the .shape and .strides attributes but doesn't touch the underlying data.